# Simple find and replace

Tags: php, regex, wordpress-theming

I am trying to make sure all YouTube embeds have two attributes from the API. I'm trying to find and replace all of:

```
rel=0&
```

with

```
rel0&theme=light&autohide=1&
```

So far, I've got this, from an [online tester](http://www.phpliveregex.com/), which apparently finds  `rel=0&`:

```
preg_replace("/(.*), (.*)/", "$0 --> $2 $1", $input_lines); ()
```

However, I am unsure how utilise the above to replace the above code with `rel0&theme=light&autohide=1&`

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
str_replace("rel=0&", "rel0&theme=light&autohide=1&", $input_lines);
```

If you have `&amp;`, you can do this:

```
str_replace(array('rel=0&', '&amp;'), array('rel0&theme=light&autohide=1&', '&') ,$input_lines);
```

Comment: May want to also search for `&amp;` in case the `&` is encoded.

Comment: This is WordPress, would it convert &amp; automatically?

Comment: If it's a link it shouldn't be @SetSailMedia ? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Sometimes the WordPress editor uses &amp; when editing a post.

Comment: Yes, WordPress does this conversion when it applies `the_content` filter. So while it may not be stored in the database with `&`, it will be output to `the_content()` as `&amp;` (and likewise any place that `the_content` filter is applied)

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect this, thanks :) @SetSailMedia

Answer (score 0):

You can just use str_replace:

```
str_replace('rel=0&','rel0&theme=light&autohide=1&',$input_lines)
```

Comment: Thanks. The only tester generated `$input_lines`, what is that parameter for?

Comment: $input_lines is the string you are doing the replacing in.